# Assign object to another object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my app, a Person can have a GuardianSpirit which is given to them by a god. Initially they don't have one. A GuardianSpirit only exists in relation to a Person, so that person must have been created already.

These are my classes:

```
public class Person {
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual GuardianSpirit GuardianSpirit { get; set; }
}

public class GuardianSpirit {
    [Key, ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

The list of persons shows a create button if there's no GuardianSpirit associated with a Person. When a user with the "God" role clicks, it shows the form to create that Person's GuardianSpirit. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1anr.png).

How do I pass the Person's id to create it? (It will have the same id as its owner)

Thanks!

Comment: It appears you are incorrectly creating objects.  Typically when designed a database (your objects in this case) each object most of the time has a Primary Key that is not used as a Primary Key for another object.  The way it appears now, a GuardianSpirit can *ONLY* be long to a single person.  I could be wrong.

Comment: [EF COde First Navigation](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-code-first-navigation-properties-and-foreign-keys/)

Comment: Yes, that's what I intend to do. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). As you can see on that page, an OfficeAssignment has an Instructor primary key because it can only exist related to an Instructor.

Comment: I would suggest that the requirement of having the PK of the GuardianSpirit the same as the Person is not required. Typically each entity is a separate DB table and has it's own PK

Comment: In any case, how do I pass the Person's id?

Answer (score 2):

In `1:0..1` associations it is normal for the optional entity to have a primary key that is a foreign key at the same time. This is the best thing a relational database can do to guarantee that both ends of the association exclusively belong to one another.

Your classes correctly implement this pattern: `GuardianSpirit` is the optional (or *dependent*) entity, `Person` is the independent (or *principal*) entity.

The consequence is that the optional entity isn't free to choose/generate its own primary key. You have to set it in your code. There are two ways to do this:

- You know the `Person`'s id: `newGuardianSpirit.PersonId = person.Id`.
- You have a `Person` object: `person.GuardianSpirit = newGuardianSpirit`.

The first option is possible because `GuardianSpirit.PersonId` won't be an identity column (when EF creates the database), so its value is not generated by the database.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply set the `Person` on the new `GuardianSpirit`. But make sure you use the `Create()` method on the DbSet so that you get a proxy object. That way when setting the `Person` the `PersonID` will also be automatically set. See the documentation [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) regarding navigation properties.

```
var person = dbcontext.Person.Create();
person.FirstName = "Bob";
person.LastName = "Roberts";
person.Age = 24;
dbcontext.Person.Add(person);
// dbcontext.SaveChanges(); // person will have a new ID if it is saved here

var guardian = dbcontext.GuardianSpirit.Create();
guardian.Name = "Luke";
guardian.Person = person;
dbcontext.GuardianSpirit.Add(guardian); // If the person was saved then the PersonID should now also be set
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

The database is incorrectly designed because PersonID in class GuardianSpirit is both foreign and primary key.

The problem is that now you can't create a guardian spirit with a proper Person's id because it's the primary key of the GuardianSpirit entity.

It should be rather:

```
public class Person {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public virtual GuardianSpirit GuardianSpirit { get; set; }
}

public class GuardianSpirit {
    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.None )]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can just create new GuardianSpirit instance, give it name and set PersonID of the Person you want it to be assigned. Then you can add this object to database using Entity Framework and save changes.

```
//here read person id
var personId = 5;
var guardianSpirit = new GuardianSpirit()
{
   Name = "Gabriel",
   PersonID = personId
};
//_context is DbContext
_context.GuardianSpirirts.AddObject(guardianSpirit);
_context.SaveChanges();
```